# Make sure function from React.useContext is called in Jest

Tags: reactjs, axios, jestjs, mocking, react-hooks

Given a custom hook that looks like this:

```
const getSavedInfo (id) => {
  const endpoint = getEndpoint(id)
  const {updateInfo} = React.useContext(infoContext)

  axios.get(endpoint).then((res) => {
   if (res) {
     updateInfo(res.data)
    }
  })
}
```

How would I go about properly mocking the updateInfo method so I can make sure it was called within my jest test?

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If I execute the `getSavedInfo` function, I will get `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.` error. So your code is incomplete. What's `infoContext` and `getEndpoint` functions? Do you want to mock `updateInfo` function or just spy it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the provider in test while rendering the custom hook. You can write your own provider function or use `react-hooks-testing-library` which does the same thing for you. Like this:

```
import { renderHook } from 'react-hooks-testing-library';

const wrapper = ({ children }) => (
  <InfoContext.Provider value={{updateInfo: jest.fn}}>{children}</InfoContext.Provider>
);


it('should call update info', () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => getSavedInfo(), { wrapper });
  
  // rest of the test code goes here
});
```

You can find detailed explanation [here](https://kevsoft.net/2019/05/28/testing-custom-react-hooks.html)